# Get attribute of a field from a VHDL record type

Tags: attributes, vhdl

Consider the following VHDL record:

```
type big_record_t is record
    field_a : unsigned(15 downto 0);
    field_b : unsigned(23 downto 0);
end record;
```

Is it possible to get attributes on the record fields **without** instantiating the record itself? eg

```
signal ex : unsigned(big_record_t.field_a'range);
```

modelsim reports the following error:

```
(vcom-1260) Type mark (big_record_t) cannot be prefix of selected name.
```

I know that getting the attribute of a instantiated signal is possible but for this specific situation I want to get the type attributes from the type itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use the `'range` attribute on a *type* <sup>†</sup>, which is what you are trying to do in your code. If you were to do something like this:

```
signal big_record_instance : big_record_t;
signal ex : unsigned(big_record_instance.field_a'range);
```

It should work, because you are now trying to get the range of an instance, not a type.

An alternative if you don't have an instance might be to have your width based on constants in the same package that your record type is defined, something like this:

```
constant field_a_width : integer := 16;

type big_record_t is record
        field_a : std_logic_vector(field_a_width-1 downto 0);
        field_b : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
end record;

signal ex : std_logic_vector(field_a_width-1 downto 0);
```

Or perhaps

```
constant field_a_width : integer := 16;

subtype field_a_type is std_logic_vector(field_a_width-1 downto 0);

type big_record_t is record
        field_a : field_a_type;
        field_b : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
end record;

signal ex : field_a_type;
```

† *see exception in comments*

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I know that I can do attributes on the instance. In this specific case I am wondering why I cant do it on the type. All the type information should be available to the compiler.

Comment: @Maurice the information might be there, but the standard doesn't support what you want to do. I've updated my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct. I guess this feature also hasn't been added to VHDL2008.

Comment: @Maurice Mostly true.  It is possible to use `'range` on items other than instances.  The `'range` attribute is available for scalar and array types, but not for other types.  For example, if I define `subtype my_range is range 0 to 31;`, then `my_range'range` is defined.  Or if I define `type my_array is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);`, then `my_array'range` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

One other suggestion is to do something like:

```
subtype field_a_range is range 15 downto 0;
subtype field_b_range is range 31 downto 0:
type big_record_t is record
    field_a : unsigned(field_a_range);
    field_b : unsigned(field_b_range);
end record;
```

Then later you can do something like:

```
signal ex : unsigned(field_a_range);
```

Another fix might be to use a function that is a bit goofy--use a function.  Though this effectively creates an instance (though hides it a bit).

```
function field_a_length return natural is
  variable tmp : big_record_t;
begin
  return tmp.field_a'length;
end function field_a_length;
```

Then use it as:

```
signal ex : unsigned(field_a_length-1 downto 0);
```